# Select2 y Entradas multiples

Tags: php, javascript, html, select2

Hola Tengo una incidencia tengo un programa de entradas multiples para agregar productos y me funciona perfectamente pero al incorporarle un select2 para buscar los articulos en los selects,  no se envian los datos correctamente, creo que el problema esta en el JQUERY,

este es el código:

```js
Para el Select2

<script>
        $("#single").select2({
        placeholder: "SELECCIONE UN PRODUCTO",
        allowClear: true
      });
</script>

Para el las entradas multiples

<script>
    $(function(){
    // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
    $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
      $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla");
      
    });
   
    // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<table class="table-responsive"  id="tabla">
                                              <tr class="fila-fija">
                                                <td>
                                                  <select  id="single" class="js-states form-control" name="producto[]" required>
                                                    <?php while($rowProducto=mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoProducto)){ ?>
                                                      <option value="<?php echo $rowProducto['idProducto']; ?>"> <?php echo $rowProducto['idProducto'].' | '.$rowProducto['desProducto'];?></option>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                  <input required  class="form-control" name="cantidad[]" step="any" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="CANTIDAD"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="eliminar">
                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg"></i></button>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
```

Comment: al agregar filas el selector `#single` ya no funcinaria. ya que un `id` deberia de ser unico en el documento. deberias de utilizar `class`, aunque no es toda la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Actualización:

No es recomendable aplicar *select2* en la fila que se va a clonar, porque hay conflicto con los nuevos *select*. La opción es tenerla oculta, clonarla y, solo entonces, usar *select2*.

Si mantienes la fila en la misma tabla, vas a estar enviando un par de campos producto/cantidad vacíos al procesar el formulario; para evitarlo, crea una tabla oculta fuera del formulario.

Como la fila origen está oculta, al cargar la página hay que ejecutar la función *agregar* para que la tabla no quede vacía.

```js
$(function(){
    // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
    function agregar() {
      // Obtener fila, remover clase y agregar a tabla
      let fila = $("#oculta .fila-fija").clone();
      fila.removeClass('fila-fija');
      fila.appendTo("#tabla");
      // Aplicar select2
      $(fila).find('select').select2({
          placeholder: "SELECCIONE UN PRODUCTO",
          allowClear: true
      });
    }
    // Evento para botón Agregar fila
    $("#adicional").on('click', agregar);
   
    // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
         var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
         // No borrar la primera fila, porque es la que se usa para clonar
         if(parent.className != 'fila-fija') {
             $(parent).remove();
         }
    });
    // Agregar fila en la carga de la página
    agregar();
});
```

```css
#oculta, .fila-fija {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-responsive" id="tabla">
</table>
<button id="adicional">Agregar fila</button>


<!-- Esta table debe quedar fuera del formulario -->
<table id="oculta">
                                              <tr class="fila-fija">
                                                <td>
                                                  <select name="producto[]" class="js-states form-control" name="producto[]" required>
                                                    <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Producto 2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Producto 4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Producto 5</option>
                                                </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                  <input required  class="form-control" name="cantidad[]" step="any" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="CANTIDAD"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="eliminar">
                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg"></i></button>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hermano muchas gracias exactamente esa es la solución lo unico que tuve que modificarle fueron los corchetes en producto quedando así

`[$("[name^=producto[]]").select2({

        placeholder: "SELECCIONE UN PRODUCTO",

        allowClear: true

});`

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Hola disculpa jajaja no me habia fijado que al colocar eso me dio un error de consola y no se veia el select2 por lo q si me tomaba los cambios pero era porque el sistema no reconocia esta variable  name^=producto[]] , es decir que mi problema aun continua

Comment: En respuesta a lo que me comentaste si se esta enviando porque el `name= producto[]` es un arreglo, luego con un whilte el envia los datos segun la cantidad de items que agregue, el tema es que al agregar un nuevo select el anterior se cambia por el item1 en vez del item que elegí

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de los problemas al clonar cuando ya está activo _select2_. Modifiqué la respuesta y ya está funcionando correctamente.

Comment: funciona el cloando pero no el select 2 amigo me sale esto:
`p_EntradaProducto.php:436 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).select2 is not a function
    at agregar (p_EntradaProducto.php:436)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (p_EntradaProducto.php:453)
    at fire (jquery.js:3221)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3351)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3799)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3809)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3351)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3799)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3809)`

Comment: Olvidado ya lo resolvi coloque el CDN del select 2 dentro de la multi entrada y me funciona , sigo probando y te comento

Comment: hice todas las pruebas correspondientes y nada que decir eres un crack xD muchas gracias