# ¿ Como insertar un ciclo while(php) en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html5, bootstrap

Resulta de que necesito una tabla que me funcione como formulario, es decir que en la tabla deben ir campos
que se llenarán con datos, no se imprimirá nada. Necesito dos botones de eliminar y agregar fila, Ya tengo ese código pero hay un problema en uno de los campos del formulario que esta en la tabla, hay un select ese select tiene código php,  y para agregar ese select cuando le doy click al boton agregar fila, no me lo permite ya que es codigo php dentro de javascript, que puedo hace para solucionarlo?

Aqui esta mi tabla(la parte del php)

```
  </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td> <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo"> </td>
                    <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"> </td>
                    <td>
                    <select class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="unidad_medida">
                    <?php
                    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_u_medida)){ //array recorre datos                               
                      ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo']?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>  </option>
                    <?php } ?> 
                    </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text"  name="cantidad"> </td>
                      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="date"  name="fecha_vencimiento"></td>
                      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="precio_unitario" > </td>
                      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="precio_total"> </td>
                  </tr>             
                </tbody>
```

Aqui esta el script que hace funcionar a los botones agregar y eliminar fila

```
    <script>
      var myTable = document.querySelector("table"); 
       function agregarFila(){ 
        var row = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo">';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">';;
        cell3.innerHTML = ' <select class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="unidad_medida">
                              <?php
                              while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_u_medida)){ //array recorre datos                               
                                ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo']?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>  </option>
                            <?php } ?> 
                            </select>';;
                                    
        cell4.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text"  name="cantidad">';;
        cell5.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="precio_unitario"';;
        cell7.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text" name="precio_total"';;
        }
  
       function eliminarFila(){
        var rowCount = myTable.rows.length;
        if(rowCount <= 1) {
          alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
        } else {
          myTable.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
        }
    
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: PHP se ejecuta en el servidor. JavaScript en el cliente.
Un navegador es un cliente, nunca va a poder interpretar php. Una vez que la página está carga, tan solo javascript va a poder modificarla, ya no hay más php.

Comment: Te faltan cerrar los tags en `cell5` y `cell6`

Comment: Sería más conveniente tener una tabla oculta con contenido por defecto y simplemente la clonas cuando necesites agregar una fila. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373241/select2-y-entradas-multiples/373484#373484), solo quita la parte correspondiente a `select2`

Comment: Quizás utilizando datatables , se genera la tabla , se rellena con los datos desde tu consulta y colocas los botones en las celdas que necesites.  te dejo la pagina de soporte de esta https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problema:

El problema es que estas usando comillas simples (`'`) para generar una cadena "multi-línea" y `Javascript` esto no se puede hacer así.

**Demo:**

```js
let multiLineStr = 'Hola 
  mundo';
  
console.log(multiLineStr)
```

---

### Solución:

Para crear cadenas "multi-línea" podes:

- Escapar (`\`) el salto de línea al final de la cadena

```js
let multiLineStr = 'Hola \
  mundo';
  
console.log(multiLineStr)
```

- o usar [plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

```js
let multiLineStr = `Hola 
  mundo`;
  
console.log(multiLineStr)
```

---

### Caso específico:

En tu caso (*y solo si el `script` este en un archivo `PHP`*), usando plantillas de cadena, podrías hacerlo así:

```
//... código anterior
cell3.innerHTML = `<select class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="unidad_medida">
                     <?php while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_u_medida)){ ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo']?>"><?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?></option>
                     <?php } ?> 
                   </select>`;
```

Comment: Para el que puso el `-1`, aca le dejo [una demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8e64347047a1f55dce15dba92fae2e578590fe2)

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias! ya funcionó pero el codigo php no se ejecuta aun dentro del javascript incluso cuando el archivo esta en extensión php

Comment: @KAROLYULIETHPACHECORODRIGUE, supongamos que un archivo `index.php` contiene `HTML`, `CSS` (`<style>`) y `JS` (`<script>`); `PHP` se compila en el servidor y el resultado es devuelto al cliente (_el navegador_) quien es el que realmente interpreta el resultado. Si no te anduvo es por alguna otra razón.